# evaluateJavaScript in PyQt does not redirect me to the next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, pyqt4, qwebview

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import sys
from time import time, sleep

class Browser(QWebView):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Browser, self).__init__()
        self.page().frameCreated.connect(self.print_load_finished)

    def print_load_finished(self):
        frame = self.page().mainFrame()
        document = frame.documentElement()
        button = document.getElementById("navPromotionBtn")
        button.evaluateJavaScript("this.click()")
        #or frame.documentElement().evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('navPromotionBtn').click()")

if __name__=='__main__':


    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    first = Browser()
    first.show()
    first.load(QUrl('https://www.bet-at-home.com/en/sport/today'))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can someone please tell me why this is not working, when everything is good under console (thats the strangest of all).. When i try it `document.getElementById("navPromotionBtn").click()` everything is ok.

Comment: I hope someone will give me some suggestion if not solution to this.. Mabye alternative.. Thank you all

Comment: Have your enable javascript in `QWebView`? Try set in `self.settings ().setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)`

Comment: Kitsune thank you for your answer. I added it, but the same thing. Can you give me another suggest please? This is killing me